# OpenCV Grey Box - Not Loading Image?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am taking a class to learn OpenCV this semester and I feel like I am just a step below my knowledge of computers for it perhaps.  I have always been pretty good with coding but it is the surrounding framework that I don't understand exactly.  For example, it took about four hours for me to install the 2.4.6 OpenCV library and Visual Studio 2012 for my Windows 7 64x pc.

Anyways, I got it and now am trying to figure out the basics.  I learned C three years ago and haven't used it since, so I am catching up on that, and self-teaching C++ based off that but my main question is why in the below sample code I found in my book, the image doesn't load.  It simply returns a 200px grey square in the window.

```
#include <highgui.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    argv[1] = "DSC00035.JPG";
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( "Example1", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
}
```

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You might be writing out of the `argv` array bounds with the instruction `argv[1] = "DSC00035.JPG"`.  Try to pass the filename string directly to the cvLoadImage function.

Comment: I just tried that and got the same result - grey box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleve that you run your program from IDE, and not set working directory to your .exe file location. Try to run exe not from the IDE (make sure image in exe location), or use full path to file.